# In a Group, is the existence of the left identity equivalent to the existence of the unique two sided identity?

Tags: group-theory

I've read many definitions in different books, and some of them specifically point out in their definition the existence of left inverse, left identity, and associativity. But the grand majority does not make this distinction, why would this be?
Plus, reading Kripke's Introduction to Analysis, there's an example that reads: "A commutative group  can have only one identity." Is this just a syntax problem, or is it possible for a non-abelian group to have more than one identity? Wouldn't that be a semi-group?

Comment: A set with an associative operation can have at most one identity. Groups, though, can be caracterized in many ways, and sometimes people prefer "minimal" set of conditions (like only imposing things on the left, say)

Comment: Ah, this makes more sense than what I had on mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $L\cdot A=I$ that is $L$ is a left inverse of $A,$ and $A\cdot R =I$ that is $R$ is a right inverse. Then $$L=L\cdot (A\cdot R)=(L\cdot A)\cdot R=R.$$ A similar argument can show that the identity is also unique.

Comment: But this uses the existence of left inverse and right inverse, from the definition we only have the left inverse. I don't see how one gets the right inverse or the right identity purely from the existence of left inverses and identities.
Or is it somewhere akin:
(L*A)=(L*I*A)=((L*I)*A)=(L*(I*A)), where I is left identity, A is any element of the group, and L is its left inverse?

Comment: It is answered nicely below by kag.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. if $a$ is a left identity and $b$ is a right identity, then $a=ab=b$ (since the right identity times $a$ is $a$, and the left identity times $b$ is $b$).

Similarly, if $e$ is the identity and $h$ is a right inverse of $g$, then $g=eg=(gh)g=g(hg)\implies hg=e\implies h$ is a left inverse of $g$.